# What is the configure command and how can I install & use it?

Tags: qt, deployment, command-line, build, configure

I am following the tutorial at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html to deploy a qt application and I am trying to run the configure command in the first step.  My system cannot seem to find the command.  I have run the command from windows command prompt, git bash, and msys.  I don't really understand what the configure command does or where it comes from.  Can anyone explain what it does & where I can get it?

Comment: The `configure` script should be located in the Qt sources directory. I.e. you have to `cd C:\path\to\Qt` first.

Answer (score 2):

`configure` is normally a (generated) shell script which is packaged in Unix-based applications and is used to detect certain machine settings and set up needed files for `make` to do its job.

Look for a `configure.bat` or a file called `configure` in the QT directory and run it.

Comment: Any idea where configure would be at in the QT directory? I'm not having much luck finding it. @vahancho

Comment: @firelight, If you are on Windows, which it appears that you are, use the graphical Search utility to search for the filename `configure`, with the install path of QT as the folder to search.

Comment: the only things I found were a profile (.prf) file, a html file, and some png's - any idea where I can get a configure file for qt?

Comment: @firelight, Exactly which QT package did you download? It sounds like you may have downloaded a binary package instead of source.

Comment: qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012_opengl-5.3.0.exe

Comment: @firelight, I do not have a Windows system handy, but [this link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Get_The_Source#ca563080636f20bdea6cfddd4d6c2645) may help you.\

Answer (score 1):

I have a shortcut to command window under:

```
Start > All Programs > Qt 5.3.0 > mingw > Qt 5.3.0 for Desktop
```

It starts Windows command window with parameters:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /A /Q /K D:\Programowanie\Qt5.3\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\qtenv2.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

In qt5 under Windows 10, I get this error when running configure:

```
configure.bat not found. Did you forget to run "init-repository"?
```

init-repository is a perl script in the repo. You can run it thusly:

```
perl init-repository
```

Then you should be able to run the configure script as per the instructions. However, I am following the [github readme](https://github.com/qt/qt5), and I am from the future.